# onClick function firing without click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've got an extremely basic setup of a `Button` and a `Dialog`. The `Dialog` open state is opened via an `onClick` function on `Button`. The `Dialog` has a hidden `input` field. When the user inputs text and hits 'Enter', the dialog should close and a search function is initiated.

The problem I'm experiencing is that when 'Enter' is hit, the `onClick` function on the button is also triggered. So, I can see in the logs that the dialog is closed, search function is initiated, and the dialog is immediately reopened.

```js
 const handleClose = () => {
    console.log("closing dialog");
    updateState({
      showDialog: false
    });
  };

  const handleKeyDown = ({ key, target: { value } }) => {
    if (key === "Enter") {
      console.log("Enter hit!");
      handleClose();
      searchForLocalEntries(value);
    }
  };

  const handleOpen = () => {
    console.log("opening dialog!");
    updateState({
      showDialog: true
    });
  };

  const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setInputValue(value);
  };

return (
    <>
      <Button
        color="secondary"
        type="button"
        variant="contained"
        onClick={handleOpen}
      >
        <AddIcon className={classes.largeButtonIcon} />
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        fullScreen={fullScreen}
        open={state.showDialog}
        onClose={handleClose}
        classes={{ paper: classes.AddToInventoryRoot }}
      >
       <DialogContent>
         ...
       </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
```

Any help on what I'm missing here would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Edit Dialog_Example]

Comment: Have you tried using `stopPropagation();`? I think since the input is hidden, button still has focused state that propagates the Enter event.

Comment: Yap strange, when replaced by onMouseUp, it works well.... I used you sandbox and ... no idea...

Comment: @RezaGhorbani, how would the event be bubbling to a button that is outside of it's element tree? Wouldn't that only be effective if `Dialog` were a child of `Button`?

Comment: @technicallynick It was just a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is easy enough. Calling `event.preventDefault()` when `key === "Enter"` (which prevents the "default" browser behavior of triggering a click when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit on a button):

```
  const handleKeyDown = event => {
    const {
      key,
      target: { value }
    } = event;
    if (key === "Enter") {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("Enter hit!");
      handleClose();
      searchForLocalEntries(value);
    }
  };
```

[image: Edit Dialog_Example]

The reason why that is necessary is a little less straightforward. When you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the dialog is closing and focus is moving from the hidden input back to the button. The browser appears to use the element that ends up with focus when deciding whether to trigger a click event on <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Below is an example that shows this aspect in isolation. Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> within the input moves focus to the button. The second input has `event.preventDefault();` added to see the difference with and without this fix. For the first input, the click is registered on the button (shown by the increment of the count) when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit within the input.

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const buttonRef1 = React.useRef();
  const buttonRef2 = React.useRef();
  const [count1, setCount1] = React.useState(0);
  const [count2, setCount2] = React.useState(0);
  const handleKeyDown1 = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      buttonRef1.current.focus();
    }
  };
  const handleKeyDown2 = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      event.preventDefault();
      buttonRef2.current.focus();
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onKeyDown={handleKeyDown1} />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setCount1(count1 + 1)} ref={buttonRef1}>
        I get focus when you hit Enter in the input
      </button>{" "}
      Count: {count1}
      <br />
      <br />
      <input onKeyDown={handleKeyDown2} />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setCount2(count2 + 1)} ref={buttonRef2}>
        I get focus when you hit Enter in the input
      </button>{" "}
      Count: {count2}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit show button click on enter after focus change]

Related documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I assumed there would be no element with focus when the dialog was unmounted. I also assumed that the `Button` wouldn't be triggered as a default action of the browser when the `input` had focus unless it was within a `form`.  Thanks for clearing this up for me! It was really frustrating!